# How to change the color of a circle annotation?

Tags: c#, itext

Hi I am adding a SquareCircle annotation to an already existing PDF using iTextSharp in C#.

Now I want to change the Fill Color annotation property ... with no results until now.
Opening a pdf the Fill Color property is in the Appearance tab of the annotation properties.

[image]

I'm using the 5.5.5.0 version of iTextSharp.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Is there a reason why you refer to the *interior color* property as the *fill color* property? Please explain in your own words what you mean by fill color and what is so different about it vis-a-vis the interior color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [CircleAnnotation](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/CircleAnnotation) example. It creates a circle annotation with a blue border and red as the interior color:

[image]

The code to add this annotation looks like this:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(150, 770, 200, 820);
    PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.createSquareCircle(
        stamper.getWriter(), rect, "Circle", false);
    annotation.setTitle("Circle");
    annotation.setColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
    annotation.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
    annotation.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0, 0, 2, new PdfDashPattern()));
    annotation.put(PdfName.IC, new PdfArray(new int[]{1, 0, 0}));
    stamper.addAnnotation(annotation, 1);
    stamper.close();
}
```

I based this example on an example from the [official documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book), more specifically the [MovieTemplates](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=151) example.

The only thing I added was the line that sets the interior color:

```
annotation.put(PdfName.IC, new PdfArray(new int[]{1, 0, 0}));
```

If you need a C# example: the examples I wrote for my book were ported to C#, you can find them here: [chapter 7: C# examples](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter07/)
It shouldn't be a problem to change the `put()` into `Put()` to make it work for you.

**Caveat:** some PDF viewers (such as Chrome PDF viewer) are not full PDF viewers. They don't support every type of annotation. For instance, if you open [hello_circle.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/hello_circle.pdf) in Chrome, you won't see the annotation. That is not a problem caused by the PDF (nor iTextSharp), that is a viewer problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruno, it work fine, but there is one other thing that doesn't work: the transparency.

Comment: I found in the documentation to add this code:   annotation.Put(PdfName.ca, new PdfNumber(0.3d));  where 0.3 is the transparency, but doesn't work.   Please where I'm wrong?                                          thanks

Comment: @LupettoBurlone When I read comments on my phone (like I am doing now), the "notification" of unread comments is changed into "read". I can't answer questions that involve running and testing code on my phone. I hope that this explains why using a comment to ask an extra question is not smart. Neither do you create any goodwill to answer subsequent questions if you don't accept an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks Bruno! It's the first time I write in a forum, so I will you forgive me. Your answer was very helpfull and solved my problem! Now I have another problem, but I post it not as a commen ... sorry again

Comment: Please accept this answer if it solved your problem. You also mentioned another problem, but I didn't find the corresponding question.